# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Config' not found

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-devtools

Hello im trying to install phalcon and devtools but something is going wrong. I did everything I saw in tutorials installed phalcon, changed the php.ini, intalled devtools but it still doesn't no work.

[image: php version]

[image: phalcon devtools]

but when i try to create a project...

[image: this happens]

Comment: That is strange, because here https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/Config/Config.zep you can see that `new \Phalcon\Config\Config()` is the right way. But here https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/master/src/Builder/Component/AbstractComponent.php is this used `use Phalcon\Config`. See https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/issues/1529

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the versions of devtools, phalcon and php. I was using php 7.4.26, phalcon 5.1 and devtools 4.2 and it was incompatible so i installed phalcon 4.0.6 and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Phalcon Dev tools, but check the Phalcon installation in php itself. Try: `php -i | grep 'phalcon'`

Answer (score 0):

You can download at https://github.com/daleffe/phalcon-devtools-5.x-fixed
and replace ....Composer/vendor/phalcon/devtools/ is's working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).